# SIGSEV on strcpy to a char pointer

Tags: c, strcpy

Why do i get a crash on `strcpy` even. I tried appending a 0,\0,\n using sprintf and check in gdb that its appended correctly but still i get a crash.
With malloc i dont get a crash, but somebody told me that malloc is not necessary in this case.

```
include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 10

int main()
{

        char* str[100];
        int strCount=0;

        char cCmd[] = "<some command>|awk '{print $1}'";
        FILE *fp;
        fp = popen(cCmd,"r");


        if(cCmd != NULL)
        {
                char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
                while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL )
                {
                        //str[strCount]=malloc(MAX_LINE_SIZE);
                        //sprintf(line,"%s%c",line,'\0'); -- even with appending a null character at the end it doesnt work
                        strcpy(str[strCount],line);
                        //strip(str[strCount]);
                        (strCount)++;
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: "someone told me" isn't a great way to learn programming ... I would suggest learning from reference material with a good reputation, that you can trust is telling you the right thing

Comment: Your commented-out `sprintf` would be undefined behaviour ,it's not permitted to have the source and destination overlap for `sprintf` (or `strcpy` for that matter)

Comment: Ok. Well without sprintf, is the only reason for crash a non null termination char probably in ‘line’?

Comment: @anurag86 What does the pointer at `str[strCount]` *point to* ? Hmm.... The "someone" that told you it didn't require `malloc` probably meant to say "you don't need `malloc` to manage memory here". Just use an array of arrays; not an array of pointers.

Comment: I am asking this because in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810234/sigsev-on-strcmp-of-memset-string somebody said mlloc isnt needed when asked "is malloc() needed for char*[]" i was told that its not needed. Hence this question

Comment: @anurag86 the answer said that there is hardly ever a reason to use **malloc in C++** because you'd use other mechanisms there. Yet this remark was only because you had incorrectly tag the question with C++.

Comment: @anurag86 You absolutely need to allocate memory for a pointer before you use `strcpy` to copy a string into that pointer. What we were trying to tell you in that other question is that `malloc()` is *not* the only way of performing such allocation.  There are other ways.

Comment: True statement: A pointer must point to valid memory before you can use it, for example, before you can use `strcpy` to copy a string "into" it.  False statement: You must use `malloc` to initialize a pointer before you can use it.

Comment: True statement: You do not need to call `malloc` to initialize a pointer before using it; there are other ways.  False statement: You do not need to call `malloc` to initialize a pointer before using it; you can just go ahead and use it uninitialized.

Comment: @anurag86 Please read all the answers at [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810234/sigsev-on-strcmp-of-memset-string/56810526) -- I'm not sure you got everything out of them.  Also, did you read the resulting [chat session](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195709/discussion-between-anurag86-and-eerorika)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this statement `strcpy(str[strCount],line)`

`char *str[100];` declares an array of 100 uninitialized pointers whereby each pointer needs to be allocated memory explicitly.

When you run `str[strCount]=malloc(MAX_LINE_SIZE);` statement, you are actually allocating memory for invidual pointers which is further used by strcpy to copy string.

When you are not using malloc, its an uninitialized pointer (having no allocated memory) causing strcpy to fail as you are coping in memory that may not belong to you or may not exist at all.

Comment: A little more succinct way to say it would be the `char *str[100];` declares and array of 100 *uninitialized* pointers to `char`. (but we know what you mean)

Comment: Good (hopefully with less typos than I had...) But that makes it clear the problem is one of initialization. (and the need to initialize by allocating and assigning the beginning address to a valid block of memory to each pointer as you originally noted)

Comment: I am asking this because in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810234/sigsev-on-strcmp-of-memset-string somebody said mlloc isnt needed when asked "is malloc() needed for char*[]" i was told that its not needed. Hence this question

Comment: @anurag86 That somebody is talking about a different language. None of what they are saying is applicable to C. Regardless, you cannot just take the first sentence in a complex story and run away with it.

Comment: @anurag86, If you are referring to the second point of the answer you missed out the point if not using malloc it needs to point directly to a string literal (only in C; in C++ you need a pointer to const). Or it can point to memory on the stack.